# How many elements are there in total?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that we have a collection of 12 sets, each of which has 8 elements. Every pair of sets
shares 6 elements, any collection of 3 sets shares 4 elements, and no collection of 4 sets shares any elements. How many elements are there in total?

I'm not sure my work is right. since the intersection of every pair of sets is 6, the intersection of every 3 sets  is 4, and the intersection of every 4 sets is 0, we have the union of these 12 sets equals to $12 \times 8 - \binom 82\times 6 + \binom 83\times 4 = 152$.

I'm a confused since this number is greater than $12\times 8 = 96$. And if any collection of 3 sets shares 4 elements but no collection of 4 sets shares any element, then for any forth set, it cannot contain any of the 4 shared elements of those 3 sets. Then there are at most 4 shared elements between this forth set and any set of those 3 sets. It contradicts to every pair of sets shares 6 elements. Is the problem wrong or my interpretation wrong?

Comment: The problem is defective: the conditions are inconsistent, and both of your arguments demonstrating that are correct.